# How to set delay after clicking at navi of jquery tools scrollable?

Tags: jquery, timeout, delay, jquery-tools, scrollable

I use http://jquerytools.org/documentation/scrollable/ with plugins `navigator` and `autoscrolling` for animation of banners. I have such part of the code:

```
$('.scrollable')
    .scrollable({ 
        circular: true,
        speed: 2000
    })
    .navigator({
        navi: '.navs'
    })
    .autoscroll(5000);
```

It works nice, but I want to have also opportunity to set delay time after choosing of certain banner (after clicking on one of `$('.navs')`). Is there any way to make what I want?

UPDATE. I can set `$('.scrollable').scrollable({ clickable: false ...})...` to stop scrolling at all.But I still want to continue it after certain delay.

http://jsfiddle.net/WqL8T/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/WqL8T/5/ - working example. Thanks to MichaelKaeser. I have just corrected syntax in a right way:

```
var api = $(".scrollable").data("scrollable");
$('.navs').on('click',function(){
  api.stop();
  var resume = api.play;
  setTimeout(resume, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
var api = $(".scrollable").data("scrollable");

$('.scrollable').on('click',function{
  api.stop();
  var resume = api.play();
  setTimeout(resume, 3000);
});
```

not tested

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
$('.scrollable').scrollable({ circular: true, speed: 1000 }).navigator({
    navi:'.navs',
    activeClass: 'on'
}).autoscroll({interval: 1000, autopause: false,fireDelay: 800,
interval: 4000});
});
```

Comment: Nothing changes after that.

Comment: Use that method at appropriate place..may be after `scrollable` function.

Comment: In that case also I have the same interval (4 sec). I want: usual rotation interval is 1 sec (for example), and after chosing banner - I want interval 5 sec (and between nexts banners / cycles again 1 sec)

Comment: In that case you refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594857/how-to-delay-or-firedelay-for-3-jquery-tools-scrollable-items