# scrollable get current value of item

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

i have a working sample of scroll-able with item number 1 - 24 i want to get the value of the current item but i failed.i tried doing it to alert but its not working how does one do it this is my code

UPDATE QUESTION:
i was able to get the index of the value of the scrollable now my problem is i cant find way to get the value of every index any way to get value of index in my code below?

UPDATE:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    // initialize scrollable with mousewheel support
    $(".scrollable").scrollable({ vertical: true, mousewheel: true });   
    $('#scroll').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
            //scroll down
            console.log('Down');
            alert('Down');
        }else {
            //scroll up
            console.log('Up');
            alert('Up');
        }

        //prevent page fom scrolling
        return false;
    });
}); 
</script>
```

i added this on my js its working now but its output is just UP and DOWN i cant find a way to get the exact value of the div any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title>scroll</title>

    <!-- include the Tools -->
  <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
  /* root element for scrollable */
  .scrollable {

  /* required settings */
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;

  /*
  vertical scrollables have typically larger height than width but
  not now
  */
  height: 17px;
  width: 700px;
  }

  /* root element for scrollable items */
  .scrollable .items {
  position:absolute;

  /* this time we have very large space for the height */
  height:20em;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- root element for scrollable -->
<div id="scroll" class="scrollable vertical">

  <!-- root element for the items -->
    <div class="items" style="top: 0px;">

        <div>

            <div class="item">
                1

            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="item">
                2

            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="item">
                3

            </div>
        </div>
        <div>

            <div class="item">
                4

            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="item">
                5

            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="item">
                6

            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="item">
                7

            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="item">
                8

            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="item">
                9

            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="item">
                10

            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="item">
                11

            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="item">
                12

            </div>
        </div>

        <div>

            <div class="item">
                13

            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="item">
                14

            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="item">
                15

            </div>
        </div>
        <div>

            <div class="item">
                16

            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="item">
                17

            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="item">
                18

            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="item">
                19

            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="item">
                20

            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="item">
                21

            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="item">
                22

            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="item">
                23

            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="item">
                24

            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
  </div>


<!-- javascript coding -->
<script>
$(function() {
    // initialize scrollable with mousewheel support
    $(".scrollable").scrollable({ vertical: true, mousewheel: true });

});
</script>


</body></html>
```

Comment: When you want to get value? after scroll complete?

Comment: exmaple the value is 1 then i scroll one so its 2 now i want to get the value of 2 i try this but eclipse wont save $(function() {
  
    $(".scrollable").scrollable({ vertical: true, mousewheel: true });

    .navigator()
    .autoscroll({
      interval: 3000,
      autoplay: false
    })
    .timeout(function(){
      $(this).data(".scrollable").play();
    }, 800);​
    $.fn.timeout = function(fn, delay){
     var self = this;
     setTimeout(function(){
       self.each(function(){
         fn.call(this);
       });
     }, delay);
     return this;
   };
   
    
});

Comment: Wrong jquey code.

".navigator() .autoscroll " means?

Comment: actually i dont know i just found it in here and tried it im a new programmer :)

Comment: @satinekianne, [this page](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/scripting.html) explains how to get the index of the current element of a scrollable

Comment: @Alexander thank you man really helped me was able to get index and working on getting value thank you

Comment: OP or @Alexander should answer the question so it can be accepted and not appear as unanswered.

Comment: @JSuar, For some reason, I didn't get a notification on the previous mentions. Also, he updated the question above so this doesn't answer anything anymore

Comment: @JSuar sorry was a bit busy here try this thing out you can work something out of this  http://pastebin.com/MvuDDugL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use the `mousewheel` event.  Instead use the `onSeek` method of scrollable.  Here is a working example, with the code shown below: http://jsfiddle.net/bluegeek9bluegeek9/b5xn5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".scrollable").scrollable({ 
    vertical   : true,
    mousewheel : true,
    onSeek     : function(){
       console.info("current position is: " + this.getIndex());
       console.info('current value is:', $('#scroll div.items > div:nth-child(' + (this.getIndex()+1) + ') > div.item').text());
    }
  });   

});
```

[Reference](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/scripting.html)

Comment: i can get the index mate the problem is i want to get the value not the index you have any idea?

Comment: that was really cool mate but the value is all wrong when im no 1 there is no value and when im on 2 the value is 1 but i think i can work that out thank you what should i do to adjust it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44033/discussion-between-binary-alchemist-and-satine-kianne)